# How to initialize struct char array?

Tags: c

I'm having trouble initializing a string of characters belonging to a struct. "Expression must have a modifiable lvalue". Do I need to use strcopy? I am not quite sure how to utilize this. Here is my code:

```
    typedef struct {
    char name[50];
    int attackDamage;
    int magicDamage;
    int defense;
    int power;
    int type;
} ITEM;

int main() {
    ITEM item[10];
    char itemset[5][5] = { 0 };
    char champion1[] = "Gnar";
    char champion2[] = "Vi";
    char champion3[] = "Fizz";
    char champion4[] = "Draven";
    char champion5[] = "Braum";
    item[0].name = "Brutalizer"; // Having issues here
}
```

EDIT: I did this and seems there isn't anymore errors. Is this the proper way?

```
strcpy(item[0].name, "Brutalizer");
```

Comment: "Having issues here" --- what does this exactly mean?

Comment: Note that arrays are not the same as pointers, you may confuse them easily of course, but they're not the same. A pointer, can point to an array and also to a string literal. Arrays are cannot be `lvalues` and you can't assign to an array, but you can assign to pointers. Modifying an array is ok as long as you do it within the reserved memory for them, but modifying a string literal is undefined behavior. So mixing them is a huge risk of undefined behavior. It's also conceptually wrong and indicates that the programmer probably, doesn't know what they're doing.

Comment: You should consider using `const char *` for your name.  It will be easier to initialise (and can be done in the way you first tried) and gets around any length limitations.

Comment: @zerkms I think the comment there is enough if you understand that the commented line, is woring. And it would not compile.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi the good habit is not to expect and provide compile or runtime errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`item[0].name` is an array, you cannot assign a pointer (string literal) to an
array. You need to copy the contents, in this case with `strcpy` for example:

```
strcpy(item[0].name, "Brutalizer");
```

Or if the length of the source is not know beforehand, then you can use
`strncpy` to avoid buffer overflows:

```
strncpy(item[0].name, "Brutalizer", sizeof item[0].name);
item[0].name[sizeof(item[0].name) - 1] = '\0'; // make sure that it's \0-terminated
```

or you can use `snprintf`

```
snprintf(item[0].name, sizeof item[0].name, "Brutalizer");
```

Comment: Be very careful with `strncpy()`. It does not always copy the *null* terminator. I prefer `memcpy()` and then put the *null* terminator myself. If you are going to put the *null* yourself, then don't use `strncpy()`.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi that's exactly what my codes does. In this case, I don't see a difference with `memcpy`

Comment: Use `memcpy()` instead.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi if the destination is not long enough to copy the \0-terminating byte from the source, then you have to set it yourself like I did. I see no real benefit in using `mempcy` over `strncpy` when copying from a source where the length is unknown and potentially larger than what the destination can hold.